# Inverse of the transform in the Box-Muller transform

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I am following [this](https://rh8liuqy.github.io/Box_Muller_Algorithm.html) writeup of the Box-Muller method but I am confused how they derived the inverse. In this method, they write

> Box-Muller Algorithm is a classic method to generate identical and independent standard normal random variables.
> Box-Muller Algorithm
>
> 1. Generate $U_{1} \sim$ uniform $(0,1)$ and $U_{2} \sim$ uniform $(0,1)$ where $U_{1} \perp U_{2}$
> 2. Set $R=\sqrt{-2 \log \left(U_{1}\right)}$ and $\theta=2 \pi U_{2}$
> 3. Set $X=R \cos (\theta)$ and $Y=R \sin (\theta)$
>    Overall,
>    $$
>    \begin{aligned}
>    &X=\sqrt{-2 \log U_{1}} \cos \left(2 \pi U_{2}\right) \
>    &Y=\sqrt{-2 \log U_{1}} \sin \left(2 \pi U_{2}\right)
>    \end{aligned}
>
> This can be verified by solving $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$,
>
> \begin{aligned}
> &U_{1}=e^{-\left(X^{2}+Y^{2}\right) / 2} \
> &U_{2}=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \arctan \left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)
> \end{aligned}

I am trying to understand how exactly the inverse of $X=\sqrt{-2 \log U_{1}} \cos \left(2 \pi U_{2}\right)$ and
$Y=\sqrt{-2 \log U_{1}} \sin \left(2 \pi U_{2}\right)$ was computed, i.e.

$$
\begin{aligned}
&U_{1}=e^{-\left(X^{2}+Y^{2}\right) / 2} \\
&U_{2}=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \arctan \left(\frac{X}{Y}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Looking at these formulas, I can't directly compute it so I'm not sure how they came up with their result.

Comment: Which "inverse" are you referring to? Do you mean the formulas for $U_1$ and $U_2$?

Comment: @Joe Yes exactly that

Comment: From the equations for $X$ and $Y$, if you notice the sine and cosine, then knowing that $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$, you realize you can isolate $U_1$ by squaring and adding $X$ and $Y$. To isolate $U_2$, you notice that you can eliminate $U_1$ by dividing $Y$ by $X$. Is that along the lines of what you're trying to figure out?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP disappeared.